# mod rewrite not behaving as expected

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have set up several `mod_rewrite` rules. In my live site when I click a link to the REWRITTEN URL it opens up the NON REWRITTEN URL in the address bar.

So, for example, I have this in my mod_rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule properties-for-sale\.php$ http://www.MYWEBSITE.net.au/residential/browse.php
```

When I click on the link `http://www.MYWEBSITE.net.au/residential/properties-for-sale.php` it opens it up ok but the address in the address bar is the original one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spoken to my hosting provider and they say `mod_rewrite` is working and there are no errors at their end. I am running WAMP on my local host with apache V 2.2.17.

Comment: RewriteRule works fine. I mean, the workflow is right. Where is the fail? If you have the rule `^something\.php$ some/thing/likethis.php?id=4` the address bar will be `something.php`. It is correct. Maybe are you looking for a redirect?

Comment: The problem I have is that the address bar is showing, using your example, "some/thing/likethis.php?id=4" even though the user clicked a link with the shorter URL.....v confusing

Comment: Uhm, I got it wrong, sorry. Are you using `RewriteBase`? Or have you more rules before that?

Comment: The only contents of the .htaccess file is what I have posted in the original question, so just 3 rows....should I be using RewriteBase ?

Comment: define the `[R]` flag at the and of the rule. If domain in the rule is the same as the request domain, it may use rewriting instead of redirecting.

Comment: So I just replace the last line with "RewriteRule properties-for-sale\.php$ http://www.MYWEBSITE.net.au/residential/browse.php[R]" ?

Comment: You can use RewriteBase to specify base path, then use your rewriterule. You can use `[L]` flag to say that it's the last rule. Using `[R]` flag means redirecting. **[Take a look here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^residential/properties-for-sale\.php$ /residential/browse.php [L]
```

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried this exactly as suggested and I am getting an error - The Requested URL not found.....

Comment: Got it! I changed it to

RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks


RewriteRule ^residential/properties-for-sale\.php$ /residential/browse.php [L]

I removed "RewriteBase /" - was this necessary to have in there?

Comment: If you remove the slash as I said you need RewriteBase, else you have to use the slash. Congrats :)

Comment: Thankyou for ALL your help kmsdev & Deadooshka, very much appreciated!!

Comment: I am using the following and it works as expected:

RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks


RewriteRule ^residential/properties-for-sale\.php$ /residential/browse.php [L]